# PDF2 installation but shows up an errro

Tags: pdf

I am installing PDF 2 version 1.26.0, and try to apply .numPages method , it shows the following message,can some one tell me why and what shoud I do ? thanks:

PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: reader.numPages is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use len(reader.pages) instead.

i tried len(reader.pages) and also remove the FDF 2 , and install PyPDF 2 3.0.0. but it still not working.

Comment: If this is a new project you should be using PyPDF 3, but you should clarify by what you mean by "not working" in that case. The only error you give here, you already solved correctly.

Comment: Take a moment to read [ask] and update the question accordingly.